# Switch to control an LED and a buzzer, either separately or together

Tags: switches

I have a circuit with one LED and one piezo buzzer, powered by a 9V battery. I want to attach a switch with 3 positions to do the following:

```
Only buzzer is on.
Only the LED is on.
Both the LED and the buzzer are on.
```

Can this be done with a single switch - maybe an SP3T slide switch?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following schematics serve to illustrate Peter Jennings' answer.

The two possibilities:

1. Using two diodes.

[image]

2. Using a DP3T switch.

[image]

Comment: Thanks vu2nan, I couldn't find those symbols in CircuitLab. Of course, when the diodes are in circuit their forward voltage drop has to be subtracted from the battery voltage to get the voltage across the buzzer and the LED, consequently their outputs will be slightly reduced compared to the individual on positions.

Comment: Yes, Peter, the diode solution would certainly take second place on account of the forward voltage drop.

Comment: Well, if you want to get really picky, you could always split the LED resistor in two, the smaller part in the connection between the centre pole and the junction of the diode and the rest of the resistor, so proportioned that the drop across the new resistor was the same as the drop across the diode. Then the brightness wouldn't vary when you switched through. Similarly a resistor in the direct feed to the buzzer would even out the volume. But, IMHO, a complete waste of time and components!

Answer (score 4):

Without extra components I don't think it can be done with a SP3T switch. However it can be done with a 2P3T switch.

Calling the 2 moving poles A & B and the 3 X 2 fixed poles 1A,2A & 3A and 1B,2B & 3B The battery connects to 1A, 2B, 3A & 3B whilst A goes to the buzzer and B to the LED. 1B and 2A have no connection. Obviously the other side of both the buzzer and LED go back to the other side of the battery.

In position A only the buzzer is on, in position B only the LED is on and in C they are both on.

The problem with a SP3T switch is that in positions 1 and 2 you can have either the buzzer or LED on, but, without isolating diodes (say) if you connect both the buzzer and LED to position 3 they will cross feed and both will be on at the same time no matter what position the switch is in.

Comment: My upvote for a good solution, Peter!